# Wordpress taxonomy query with both and , or condition

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, taxonomy-terms

i have **product** post type and i have **product_cat** is the taxonomy . In **product_cat** i have ***red, hard, soft, pen***  entires .

So i have to get the  **products coming under red and  it coming hard or soft**

How can i get this ?

For a product that come under both red and hard and soft i can use the following query

```
 $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                     'field' => 'slug',
                     'terms' => 'red'
                      ),
                     array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                     'field' => 'slug',
                     'terms' => 'hard'
                      ),
                     array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                     'field' => 'slug',
                     'terms' => 'soft'
                      )
                      ),
                     'post_type' => 'product',
                     'orderby' => 'title',
                     );
```

But what i need is red is must and either in soft or hard . 
ie `(red && (soft||hard ))`

Please help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this way:

```
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array( 'red' ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'hard' ),
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( 'soft' ),
                ),
        ),
    ),
```

Is untested, but it should work!

If not, here some useful links:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

https://10up.com/blog/2013/wordpress-mixed-relationship-taxonomy-queries/